# Why am I getting a javascript error in the following 3 lines of code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var pagebacklinks = new Array();    
pagebacklinks[jQuery('#somevalue').val()]["something"] = 33;
```

ERROR I GET ABOVE IS:

```
pagebacklinks[jQuery("#somevalue").val()] is undefined
//alert(jQuery('#somevalue').val());  This however shows the correct value
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because `pagebacklinks[jQuery('#somevalue').val()]` is not an array.

This should work

```
var pagebacklinks = new Array();    
pagebacklinks[1] = new Array();

pagebacklinks[1][2] = 'sadfasdf';

console.log(pagebacklinks[1][2]);
```

So the correct way should be

```
pagebacklinks[jQuery("#somevalue").val()] = new Array();

pagebacklinks[jQuery('#somevalue').val()]["something"] = 33;
```

Comment: +1 for correctness. On a sidenote, the item in the first level array could either be another array, or just an object.

Answer (score 1):

Try puting `jQuery('#somevalue').val()` into a variable first then use the variable in the array.

Comment: I concur. And if that does not help, try hardcoding the value and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript doesn't have associative arrays. You can use an object here.

```
var pagebacklinks = [],
    index = jQuery('#somevalue').val();

pagebacklinks[index] = {'something': 33};
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it:

```
var pagebacklinks = []; // [] is a shorter version than new Array()

var vKeyLevelOne = jQuery('#somevalue').val(); // May be an int, or a string - a "variant"

if (typeof pagebacklinks[vKeyLevelOne]=='undefined') pagebacklinks[vKeyLevelOne] = [];

pagebacklinks[vKeyLevelOne]["something"] = 33;
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var $val=jQuery('#somevalue').val();

var pagebacklinks = new Array();

pagebacklinks[$val]["something"] = 33;
```